How count occurrences *across all columns* in a polars dataframe?
I have an imported .csv of number values- I want to sort the dataframe so I end up a list showing how many times each value occurs across the whole dataframe.
E.g.
1: 5
2: 0
3: 23
4: 8

I have found how to count the values of a specified column, but I can't find a way to do the same thing for the entire dataframe- I could count the values of each column and then combine them afterward but it is a bit clunky and I was looking for a more elegant solution.
This is an example of what I was trying:
sort_dataframe = df.select(pl.col("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7").value_counts())

Which results in:
polars.exceptions.ComputeError: Series length 16 doesn't match the DataFrame height of 26


So you have a dataframe with multiple numeric columns and you want to  count the number of occurrences for each unique number in the dataframe across all columns?

Are all the columns of the same dtype? Can you provide an actual example?

TLDR. You can use value_counts after unpivoting the dataframe into a long format.
df.unpivot().get_column("value").value_counts()

Explanation
Let us consider the following example dataframe.
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "col_1": [1, 2, 3],
    "col_2": [2, 3, 7],
    "col_3": [1, 1, 9],
})

shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ col_1 ┆ col_2 ┆ col_3 │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 1     ┆ 2     ┆ 1     │
│ 2     ┆ 3     ┆ 1     │
│ 3     ┆ 7     ┆ 9     │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘

First, we can unpivot the dataframe using pl.DataFrame.unpivot to obtain a single column containing all values.
df.unpivot()

shape: (9, 2)
┌──────────┬───────┐
│ variable ┆ value │
│ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str      ┆ i64   │
╞══════════╪═══════╡
│ col_1    ┆ 1     │
│ col_1    ┆ 2     │
│ col_1    ┆ 3     │
│ col_2    ┆ 2     │
│ col_2    ┆ 3     │
│ col_2    ┆ 7     │
│ col_3    ┆ 1     │
│ col_3    ┆ 1     │
│ col_3    ┆ 9     │
└──────────┴───────┘

Finally, we can get the value column as a pl.Series and use pl.Series.value_counts to count the number of occurrences of each value.
counts = df.melt().get_column("value").value_counts()

shape: (5, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ value ┆ count │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64   ┆ u32   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ 7     ┆ 1     │
│ 3     ┆ 2     │
│ 9     ┆ 1     │
│ 2     ┆ 2     │
│ 1     ┆ 3     │
└───────┴───────┘

This can also be simply converted to a python dictionary.
dict(counts.iter_rows())

{3: 2, 7: 1, 1: 3, 2: 2, 9: 1}


I think value_vars=cs.all() is the same as a default melt: df.melt()

@jqurious Indeed - I've edited the answer to rely on the default. Thanks!

Huge Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for! However I ran into an issue- with.value_counts it is counting the 1 in 1 but also the 1 in 10 and 2 1's in 11 etc. so my value count for 1 is artificially high- how could I account for that?

@user24556897 Do you want to count all 1‘s (even those in 10 and 21) in the same bucket? Could you provide us with a sample input along with the expected output to clarify on the issue?

@Hericks As an example: the data set is 10 columns of data, the values in range of 1 to 100, the melt worked exactly as I wanted to bring the 10 columns down to the 2 columns, being value and frequency. I want it to count the frequency of each number 1-100 in the dataframe- the issue has arisen for the values 1-9, it counts the frequency but currently it includes 10 as 1 and 11 would also count as 2 * 1. So my values in the range 1-9 are showing as extremely high frequency. Is it .unique() that I would need to fix this?

@user24556897 Sorry, maybe I am misunderstanding, but pl.Expr.value_counts won't count the digit 1 in the numbers 10 and 11 also to the digit 1. You can simply check as follows. pl.Series("numbers", [1, 10, 11]).value_counts(). The corresponding count is 1 for all numbers (1, 10, and 11). Especially, the count for the number 1 is not 4 and the counts in your dataframe should not be artificially inflated.

@Hericks I'm confused- when I run the check- the count works but when I implement the code: counts = df.melt().get_column("value").value_counts()  I am getting artificially high numbers- am I missing something? For instance I have 318 rows in my CSV but I am getting 378 frequency for the value 6, each row doesn't have repeat values so the highest possible frequency should be 318.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@user24556897 Can you compare with df.melt().group_by("value").len() to see if the results are the same? It may help with debugging.

@jqurious Thanks for the suggestion. We managed to find the issue via chat. Accidentally, .melt() was called twice in their code leading to the incorrect result.

While not the most elegant solution, one can perform a value_counts on each of the columns, then join them up via concat and sum horizontally:
import polars as pl
from polars import col

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "col_1": [1, 2, 3, 1 ],
    "col_2": [2, 3, 7, 2,],
    "col_3": [1, 1, 9, 8 ],
})

counts = df.lazy().select(col('*').value_counts())
print(
    pl.concat(
        items=[
            counts.select(col(c).struct.rename_fields(['value', c])).unnest(c)
            for c in counts.columns
        ],
        how='align'
    )
    .select('value', pl.sum_horizontal(counts.columns).alias('count'))
    .collect()
    # shape: (6, 2)
    # ┌───────┬───────┐
    # │ value ┆ count │
    # │ ---   ┆ ---   │
    # │ i64   ┆ u32   │
    # ╞═══════╪═══════╡
    # │ 1     ┆ 4     │
    # │ 2     ┆ 3     │
    # │ 3     ┆ 2     │
    # │ 7     ┆ 1     │
    # │ 8     ┆ 1     │
    # │ 9     ┆ 1     │
    # └───────┴───────┘
)

